# Can you perform 2 methods in order by clicking on button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button

I think my question is fairly simple.
I have these 2 buttons:

```
<button @click="getPartyLeader" class="btn btn-success">Get party leader</button>
  <button @click="saveParty" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

I don't want the user to have to click on the `get party leader` button first and after that on the submit button. Is it possible to combine these buttons so that the `getPartyLeader` method is executed first and the `saveParty` method is executed when the first one is done?

**My javascript**
In case you need it:

```
import PartyDataService from "@/services/PartyDataService";
import PartyLeaderDataService from "../../services/PartyLeaderDataService";

export default {
  name: "AddParty",
  data() {
    return {
      leaderName: "",
      party: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        description: "",
        ispartynational: true,
        partyLeader: {id: null, name: "", appearance: ""}
      },
      message:"",

    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveParty() {
      var data = {
        name: this.party.name,
        description: this.party.description,
        ispartynational: true,
        partyLeader: {
          id: this.party.partyLeader.id,
          name: this.party.partyLeader.name,
          appearance: this.party.partyLeader.appearance
        }
      };
      PartyDataService.create(data)
          .then(response => {
            this.party.id = response.data.id;
            console.log(response.data);
            this.message = 'The Party was created successfully!';
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
    },
    newParty() {
      this.party = {};
    },
    getPartyLeader(){
      var leadername = this.leaderName;
      PartyLeaderDataService.findByName(leadername)
      .then(response => {
        this.party.partyLeader.id = response.data.id
        this.party.partyLeader.name = response.data.name
        this.party.partyLeader.appearance = response.data.appearance
        console.log(this.party)
      })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to do `this.getPartyLeader` at the start of the `saveParty()` method, but that was not successful.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working is your `getPartyLeader` method has an asyn component which you are not awaiting. I think the code you need is

```
async saveParty() {
    await this.getPartyLeader()
    ... // the rest of the method
},
async getPartyLeader(){
      var leadername = this.leaderName;
      // Note returning the promise
      return PartyLeaderDataService.findByName(leadername)
      .then(response => {
        this.party.partyLeader.id = response.data.id
        this.party.partyLeader.name = response.data.name
        this.party.partyLeader.appearance = response.data.appearance
        console.log(this.party)
      })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
    }
}
```

I'm assuming `PartyLeaderDataService.findByName(leadername)` returs a `Promise`

Comment: It returns an object, not a promise I think

Comment: Also it does not work, the first method does not get executed properly before the second method starts

Comment: By first method do you mean `getPartyLeader`? What do you mean does not get executed properly?

Comment: I get a 500 error that I do not get if I push them seperately and yes the first  method is getPartyLeader (that is the method that should get executed first)

Comment: Ok 500 is a server side error, so not sure how its related maybe there is a timing issue? You can look at the network requests sent using this code and when you trigger the methods separately and see it its the same? If the are then you need to understand the cause of the 500. Or if you really want add a delay in this code which is messy.